# CSS Убрать лишний пиксель у border

Tags: html, css, border

пишу сайт и я на этапе меню:  [код](http://jsfiddle.net/c7br5eg0/2/)
у каждого элемента, кроме последнего есть свойство:

```
border-right:solid 1px #fb1300;
```

как у него убрать "лишний" пиксель внизу? (он налезает на нижний border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu li {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb0800, #ba0200);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 141px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li+li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fb1300;
}

.menu li:first-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>главная</li>
  <li>Дымоходы</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задать нижнюю границу, фон и скругление для всего меню.

```css
.menu {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb0800, #ba0200);
}

.menu li { 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 141px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;  
}
.menu li:not(:last-child){
  border-right: solid 1px #fb1300;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>главная</li><li>Дымоходы</li><li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: я не совал всё в класс .menu потому-что он был больше размером чем само "меню", да это странно но всё же.. а так спасибо.